# Avoid Signals of previous days condition in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I have written a pine script which generate signal when :
the inside candle is formed around day low of at least 180 points below from day high
and a 5 minute candle closes below the inside candle.

However I want to avoid Signals of previous days condition in Pine Script ( The previous day condition is taking trade next day also ).

Screenshot of tradingview with signals[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/60njV.png)]

Another screen shot :
[image]

Attached is full code .

```
//@version=5
strategy("INSIDE_CANDLE",overlay=true)

var int len = 0
len := ta.barssince ( hour==09 and minute == 15 ) + 1

t = time('1440', session.extended)  // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
//plot(t, style=linebr) // debug
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
plotshape(is_first, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=shape.arrowdown)
day_high = float(na)
day_low = float(na)
if is_first and barstate.isnew
    day_high := high
    day_low := low
    day_low
else
    day_high := day_high[1]
    day_low := day_low[1]
    day_low
if high > day_high
    day_high := high
    day_high
if low < day_low
    day_low := low
    day_low


buffer3 = input ( 180 , title = "Must have up/down")
my_session = input.session("0930-1445", title='Enter Time Range')
t1 = time(timeframe.period, my_session)
t2 = time(timeframe.period, "1515-1520")  

last_seven_bull=(day_high-low>buffer3) 
last_seven_bear=(high-day_low>buffer3)
last_seven=last_seven_bull or last_seven_bear
bullishBar = 1
bearishBar = -1
isInside() =>
    previousBar = 1
    bodyStatus = close >= open ? 1 : -1
    isInsidePattern = high < high[previousBar] and low > low[previousBar]

    isInsidePattern ? bodyStatus : 0

dayhigh = high > ( ta.highest ( high , len ))[2]
daylow = low < ( ta.lowest ( low , len ))[2] 

high_low =   ((low<( ta.lowest ( low , len ))[1] or daylow  ) or  (high>( ta.highest ( high , len ))[1] or dayhigh ))
barcolor( (isInside()==1 or isInside()==-1 )  and last_seven and high_low ? color.rgb(7, 7, 7) : na)
alert_sell= (isInside()==1 or isInside()==-1 )  and last_seven_bull  and  high_low and t1
plotshape(alert_sell, title="Buy", style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, text="S")

tp = input.float( 150 , title = "Take Profit level"  , group = "Profit levels", inline = "s1")  
usetp = input.bool ( false , title = "Use %", group = "Profit levels", inline = "s1")  
sl = input.float( 50 ,title = "Stop loss level"  , group = "Profit and Stop levels", inline = "s2")  
usesl = input.bool ( false , title ="Use %", group = "Profit and Stop levels", inline = "s2")


var float entry_high = 0.0
entry_price_low = ta.valuewhen(alert_sell, low, 0)
plot(series=entry_price_low,color = #53cbe9)


shortCondition = close<entry_price_low  and strategy.position_size == 0 and last_seven_bull
if shortCondition 
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, comment='3', alert_message='key1')
    
short_stop_level = 0.0  
short_profit_level = 0.0  
short_stop_level := shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0 ? close+(usesl?close*0.01*sl:sl) : short_stop_level[1]  
short_profit_level := shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0 ? close-(usetp?close*0.01*tp:tp) : short_profit_level[1]  

strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Short",limit=short_profit_level,stop = short_stop_level , comment = "4" ,alert_message= "key1" ) 
strategy.close('Short', when=t2, comment='4', alert_message='key1')
```

I tried for loop and if conditions but not sure if I am using correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
If ( last candle of the day )
    strategy.cancel_all()
```

This will delete all the pending limit order when day is about to close. So that those order don't execute next day

Comment: Thank you Kapoor, How to get 'last candle of the day' this do not seem to be inbuilt function